# compare dictionary values with float number

Tags: python-3.x

How can I compare the dictionary values with float i.e if I had the following dictionary:

```
{
    'F2': 0.5896643972009248, 
    'F3': 0.5742879655443124, 
    'F1': 0.5899210024965614, 
    'F11': 0.6086413936684749, 
    'F4': 0.5924462845088885, 
    'F6': 0.5659846155839213, 
    'F10': 0.6339183933852852, 
    'F9': 0.5597757560369959, 
    'F5': 0.5633086160491567, 
    'F7': 0.556301751221009, 
    'F12': 0.8346634117283984, 
    'F8': 0.5163509611989721
}
```

and I want to compare each value in this dictionary with float and if the dictionary values are greater than the given float number the output will be each key corresponding value if not block (didn't output) the key and value.

Comment: What do you mean with "block the key and value"?

Comment: i mean didn't output

Answer (score 0):

I don't what did you mean with "block the value and key", so I'm just returning the dictionary with values greater than a given float.
You can try this solution with dict comprehension:

```py
def compare_dict_values(dictionary, given_float):
    return {i: dictionary[i] for i in dictionary if dictionary[i] > given_float}
```

Comment: @Basma Hassan, Is that solution helpful?

Comment: @ maciejwww 1 it gave an error TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: Well, you said it was a dictionary. What type is your dictionary? Did you pass arguments to my function in proper order because only the `dictionary` argument in my solution can throw such an error? Show me how you are executing it.